# Make my PC faster

Tags: pi-3

Is it possible to my make my PC faster by hooking up my Raspberry Pi 3 to it, maybe through Ethernet, USB, or HDMI? And if this is possible, how much will this boost my machine?

Answer (score 5):

No. There is almost certainly no way in which the capabilities of a Raspberry Pi exceed the capabilities of your PC. It has low USB and network bandwidth, low RAM, low CPU speed, and relatively poor graphics capabilities. Unfortunately, adding two computers together doesn't make one faster computer.